# What is the use of validating certificate in Adobe Reader

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, digital-signature, trusted-root-certificates

I've received a PDF which is digitally signed and they provided a guideline to validate the signature. I have done those steps, the signature shows as valid. I saved it as a copy and sent it back to my friend, but when he opens that, it still says the `The validity of the document certification is unknown`.

- What is digital signature for?
- If I validate it, will it triggers to the author that the user have
  validated the signature?
- What is the use of validating this?

Comment: The certification was for the original.  A copy is a new document.

Comment: Pasupathi: Did you simply make a copy of the file with a general purpose utility (e.g., Explorer or a copy command), or did you "Save as" from within Adobe Reader (or some other app) — and, if the latter, did you make *any* changes in the file first (even something trivial like clicking a checkbox)?  Also, please specify what operating system you are using (e.g., Windows or Linux) and, if convenient, provide a link to the signature validation guideline (or a very brief summary, if it's not online)?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 64 bit. Adobe reader XI. I validated the signature and used File->Save copy as option. And the Save copy as file is fine when I open in my system, After that I had added it to zip and send it to my friend, he is getting `unkown` error.

Comment: @Pasupathi: As part of the guidelines did you have to install a certificate on your system? If so then clearly your friend's system is lacking the same.

Comment: A digital signature is what it says… a signature. When you validate it, you make sure that the signature is from whom it pretends to be (and implicitely that the document is what your partner intended to send to you). That's it. The validation is for you, and not for your partner.